# amfphp what versions of flash are compatible?

Tags: flash, amfphp

Just installed AMFPHP on my local dev box and following the tutorials, all says it's installed correctly but the HelloWorld.php example doesn't work. Could this be because I'm running the incorrect version of flash in my browser? or does this even matter and it's another issue?

BTW I have chmoded all the files to 755 so I know it's not a permissions issue.

EDIT:

The side bar for the services doesn't load

Comment: where is this service sidebar you speak of?

Comment: in the vid tutorial he installed and then made the file HelloWorld.php opened up the URL: localhost/amfphp/browser and to the right side had a navigation with the newly created service. I don't have the sidebar navigation. URL to Vid: http://www.amfphp.org/tuts/install121.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The AMFPHP framework requires the Shockwave plugin as well and I'm developing on Linux which the Shockwave plugin doesn't exist yet. Hitting the URL from another (Windows) computer on the network I'm able to see the side bar.

Comment: this sounds very far fetched to me. are you absolutely positive? it may be so that the sidebar simply requires a newer flash player than the one you had installed.

Comment: running Flash 10 and Firefox 3.5.x on both machines, the only difference is one is on Linux and one on Windows and the Windows browser also has Shockwave player installed

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the location of the service gateway correctly in the initial popup?
Is the DiscoveryService.php in the amfphp subdirectory of the services folder?